# C++ Solving Diamond Inheritance Without Virtual Inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have the following diamond class structure that does not compile:

```
class Base{
  int a;
public:
  virtual void doSomething();
};

class NotMineToTouch : public Base {};

class MyParentClass : public Base {};

class EvilDiamond : public NotMineToTouch, public MyParentClass {};

// I need these methods (that I cannot necessarily edit) to work for an EvilDiamond
void processBase (Base* b) { b->doSomething; /*...*/} // Cannot edit

void processParent (MyParentClass* p) { p->doSomething; /*...*/} // Can edit

void processNotMine (NotMineToTouch* n) { n->doSomething; /*...*/} // Cannot edit
```

I know the normal solution is to inherit virtually from `Base`; however, I am not allowed to change `NotMineToTouch` (or `Base`).  Is there another solution?  I am allowed to change `MyParentClass` and `EvilDiamond` at my pleasure; however, `EvilDiamond` must inherit from `MyParentClass` and `NotMineToTouch`, and `MyParentClass` must inherit from `Base` and may not inherit from `EvilDiamond`.

Comment: I only get a warning not an error. Can you give us the actual compiler error you are getting or post code that reproduces the problem. BTW it isn't a diamond if you don't use virtual inheritance. Virtual inheritance is what merges the two bases into one creating the diamond shape if you draw it in a diagram.

Comment: We call the virtual method getA() in other places on Bases and MyParentClass (in code I am not always allowed to change).  It may not be diamond inheritance, but it is certainly the diamond problem (see the description on the tag).  Compiler error when I call getA() on an EvilDiamond:
error: request for member 'getA' is ambiguous
note: candidates are: virtual int Base::getA()
note:                 virtual int Base::getA()

Comment: Can you not cast to the right type when you pass the object?

Comment: Passer By - I cannot cast an object to something it is not (hence why I need to multiple inherit).  I see no reason to cast - if my object subclasses a base class, I can pass it where a pointer of that class is called for.  This is not an overload issue.

Comment: The following code would give that error `void processEvilDiamond (EvilDiamond* n) { n->doSomething(); }` the solution is to specify which one you want: `void processEvilDiamond (EvilDiamond* n) { n->MyParentClass::doSomething(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I challenge the following assertion:

> EvilDiamond must inherit from MyParentClass and NotMineToTouch

You can probably do something along these lines (depending on your architecture):

```
class EvilDiamond;

class NotMineToTouchImpl : public NotMineToTouch {
  EvilDiamond* tgt_;
public:
  NotMineToTouchImpl(EvilDiamond* tgt) : tgt_(tgt) {}

  ... implement NotMineToTouch here, using tgt_ where you would have used this
};

class MyParentClassImpl : public MyParentClass {
  EvilDiamond* tgt_;
public:
  MyParentClassImpl(EvilDiamond* tgt) : tgt_(tgt) {}

  ... implement Base here, using tgt_ where you would have used this
};

class EvilDiamond {
  friend class NotMineToTouchImpl;
  friend class MyParentClassImpl;

  // Creating permanent instances of the API classes 
  // may or may not be appropriate in your case.
  NotMineToTouchImpl nmti_;
  MyParentClassImpl pci_;
public:
  EvilDiamond () : nmti_(this), pci_(this) {}

  NotMineToTouchImpl* getAsNotMineToTOuch() {return &nmti_;}
  MyParentClassImpl * getAsParentClass() {return &pci_;}
};
```

Comment: Edited the original post.  I have other methods that accept a Base where I need to pass an EvilDiamond.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have diamond as you don't use virtual inheritance.
you have some **"Y"** inheritance currently (`EvilDiamond` has 2 `Base`).

Without changing your classes, you may add overloads to instruct compiler what to do:

```
void processBase (EvilDiamond* evil) {
    processBase(static_cast<NotMineToTouch*>(evil)); // Use NotMineToTouch::Base
    processBase(static_cast<MyParentClass*>(evil));  // Use MyParentClass::Base
}
```